# How to target an HTML element using rxjs fromEvent in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

**Issue**

I have used ngrx fromEvent operator to create an Observable from 2 input text fields, I have used document as target which is fine, but now I want to target only one input field. I am not sure sure what to use instead of document to target only one input field.

**What I have done so far to get the target**

- Used document.getElementByID('someID')
- Used ElementRef
- Used document.querySelector('someID')

**Code**

[StackBlits live editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-fromevent)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input type="text">
             <input type="text">`
})
export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res.target.value));
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can give the `input` field that you want to observe, a template variable.

You can use then use `@ViewChild` to get access to that `input`. And then use the `nativeElement` property on it.

Now the `nativeElement` property will only be accessible after the view has initialized. So you can use the [**`AfterViewInit`**](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) Component Lifecycle Hook in order to access it.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<input #toTarget type="text">
             <input type="text">`
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('toTarget') toTarget: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.toTarget.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res.target.value));
  }
}
```

---

> Here's an **[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-fromevent-eg?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your ref.

Comment: `@ViewChild` attributes should be accessed inside `ngAfterViewInit`, since they are set after the view has been initialized provided the element doesn't have ngIf/ngFor directives.

Comment: @SafalPillai, that makes sense. Thanks a lot for pointing it out. I've updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're reading this with Angular 8+, the correct way to reference @ViewChild-elements while being able to use them in ngOnInit is this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input #yourTarget type="text">
    <input type="text">
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('yourTarget', {static: true}) yourTarget: ElementRef;

  subscriptions = new Subscription();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    subscriptions.add(
      fromEvent(this.yourTarget.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res.target.value))
    )
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Notice the `{static: true}` inside the @ViewChild declaration:
It causes Angular to know the referenced element already in the lifeCycle "OnInit".